Placing nodes with time stamp from table in PGFPlots
Plotted are lon and lat coordinates, for which Im trying add nodes with the respective time stamps.  MWE below.
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
    time,lat,lon
    17:00,81.37045867,-3.398481833
    17:30,81.36898367,-3.402363
    18:00,81.36735233,-3.405729667
    18:30,81.36515467,-3.3996845
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                \addplot[
                    mark=x, only marks,
                    visualization depends on={\thisrow{time} \as \timestamp},
                    nodes near coords*={\timestamp}]
                    table [x=lon, y=lat, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


This obviously does not give the result I need, and it surely is a formatting issue.  Any ideas how to solve this?
I have tried working my way through the pgfplots and pgfplotstable manuals without obtaining the desired output.

See pages 38-39 of the plgfplotstable manual (date type=...).

Thanks, @JohnKormylo I already tried working my way through the manual but was not able to implement the code as needed... (edited my question accordingly)

The filecontents package is deprecated

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
time,lat,lon
17:00,81.37045867,-3.398481833
17:30,81.36898367,-3.402363
18:00,81.36735233,-3.405729667
18:30,81.36515467,-3.3996845
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[
only marks, mark=x,
nodes near coords,
point meta=explicit symbolic,
] table [x=lon, y=lat, meta=time, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



as easy as that!  many thanks @hpekristiansen

@Elmar: No need to write thank you on this site. Please accept answer :o)
